# add text to title on admin/content page drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to add some text to 'title' on admin/content page, based on content type.

for ex. if any article title is 'this is test article'. I want it to be displayed on this page like 'this is test article SOME EXTRA TEXT'.

I want to do it for 3 4 content type. for every content there will be different extra text.

How can I achieve it ??

Answer (score 0):

Easier and yet more powerful solution would be to create your own content overview page. Create a page view that will list content. Use table format and set some back-end path to that page so  you'll get the admin theme for it and it will look (almost) identical to original one. Or, make it even better - add more filtering options, make content sortable by other colomns (except for "Updated" field")...

When you do that for every field you'll have many options including most powerful one - to execute some php code on original content to generate different one...

And you can edit admin menu, to add your new page to it (eventually replace original one).

Comment: Thanks, I did it using Administration Views and Views Bulk Operations (VBO) modules.